# $addFields and calculation not working - mongodb shell

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-shell

```
db.Hours.aggregate(
  {$addFields: {TrueAmbientTemp: { {$add : [-8 , {$multiply : ["$AmbientTemp" , 47]}]}}}}
)
```

I am trying to add a new field TrueAmbientTemp which is a calculation field. The above give an error.

Comment: Also how would add this in as a seperate column to all documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss some semicolons.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $addFields: {
    TrueAmbientTemp: {
      $add: [
        -8,
        {
          $multiply: [
            "$AmbientTemp",
            47
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Example：[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AkDUT3s8QUO)

update：**you can change `update` to `updateMany`**

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      TrueAmbientTemp: {
        $add: [
          -8,
          {
            $multiply: [
              "$AmbientTemp",
              47
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example：[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7OHKbRYXaQF)

Comment: how would add this in as a seperate column to all documents ?

Comment: what do mean ? can you show some test data and what expect result would be like

Comment: ```db.Hours.updateMany({}, {$set:{"TrueAmbientTemp": {$add: [ -8,{$multiply: [  "$AmbientTemp", 47]} ]}}})```

Comment: As above so instead of an aggregate I want to update the actual documents is this possible?